# Unable to get IPV4 address into WPF (Using Runspace)

Tags: wpf, powershell, runspace

I've been working on transitioning a tool I'm creating for work from a traditional WPF, to a WPF that utilizes runspaces.  The learning curve was a bit steep, at first, but I'm starting to get the hang of it.

I'm having some trouble getting certain powershell command results to pass through to the runspace.

The most recent issue:
I have a working powershell script that will do the following

1. Resolve the IP of a computer name

```
    $resolve = resolve-dnsname $computername | select IPAddress
    $IP = $resolve -replace ".*-" -replace ".{1}$"
```

$GetIP will show me the IPV4 address in the console

2. Perform nbtstat on the IP and grab the first

```
    $NBT = IF($IP -ne "") {nbtstat -a $IP}
    foreach ($line in $NBT) {
         if($line -match '^\s**([^<\s]+)\s*<00>\s*UNIQUE')
         {
              $NBTName = $Matches[1]
              break
         }}
```

3. Return TRUE if the name associated with the IP address does not match the $computername or FALSE if they do match.

```
    $BadDNS = IF($computername -ne $NBTName -and $IP -notmatch ""){"TRUE"} ELSE {"FALSE"}
```

This works well in a standard powershell environment.  However, I cannot get this to work in my WPF form with runspaces.  I have gotten so far as discovering the issue I'm running into is the IPV4 address will not populate correctly.  When I run this command and output the $IP variable to a textbox, I'm getting something similar to the following

```
    fe80:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx %19 192.168.1.1
```

The resulting IP will of course fail any checks.  I've tried multiple methods of pulling the IPV4 address over to the WPF GUI with varying results.  None of which were acceptable.
For example:

```
    $IP = test-netconnection -computername $computername
    $IP.RemoteAddress.IPAddressToString
```

Which, again, gives me the IPV4 address in my ISE console.  However the results are unusable in the WPF, for some reason.

Does anyone have any idea of how to get this information into my GUI?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first advice I'd give you, is to ask for the `IP4Address`, instead of the `IPAddress`. Example, `$(Resolve-DNSName $Env:ComputerName).IP4Address` I would also suggest that you revisit your replace parameters, because I cannot determine what they're supposed to do to that returned data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I changed the code to .IP4Address and removed the replace paramaters.  To be honest, I can't remember why I added those to my original script.  

The return I'm getting in my WPF form is now just a blank field.  I have a feeling I'm going to have to convert the value of the IP address to some format that the WPF can understand but I don't know to what type.

Comment: … `$resolve = (Resolve-DNSName $computername).IP4Address`, is what I'd expect! So after doing so, has it resolved your initially reported issue?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I changed it to.  The output should be shown in my WPF via

    `$IP = (Resolve-DNSName $computername).IP4Address`

    `$syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{ $syncHash.TestOutput.Text = $IP })`

Comment: I was able to get an output to work!
    `(test-netconnection -computername $computername).remoteaddress.ipaddresstostring`